# GCC/CC unable to compile C project with multiple files (mac os)

Tags: c, macos, gcc, linker-errors

I am getting started with C programming as part of some course work. My IDE suggests I have constructed the following correctly (i.e. go to definition works, no red squigglies), but gcc and cc are both rejecting it with a similar error message:

`main.c`:

```
#include "help.h"

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    herp();
    return 0;
}
```

`help.h`

```
#ifndef help_herp
#define help_herp

void herp();

#endif
```

`help.c`

```
#include "help.h"

void herp() {
    // nothing
}
```

Seems pretty simple (but I am an extreme beginner with C, so I may have just left some boilerplate off). Unfortunately it's not compiling:

`gcc main.c -o out`

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_herp", referenced from:
      _main in main-538251.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

You can use `-v` but it's honestly not super helpful (or at least not to me):

`gcc main.c -o out -v`

```
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.15.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mframe-pointer=all -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=10.15.4 -fcompatibility-qualified-id-block-type-checking -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 609.8 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/richard.rast/hacks/cderp -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 254 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.15.0 -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/hy/6j_xcjw100g_037n1zmydvfc3rt5bn/T/main-6e386a.o -x c main.c
clang -cc1 version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29) default target x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -platform_version macos 10.15.0 10.15.4 -syslibroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o out -L/usr/local/lib /var/folders/hy/6j_xcjw100g_037n1zmydvfc3rt5bn/T/main-6e386a.o -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_herp", referenced from:
      _main in main-6e386a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Same issue if I use `cc`.

Note that if I skip the link step (which is, erm, important), it seems to work:

`gcc main.c -o out -c`

(generates no output, there is a file called `out` with 672 bytes in it)

so I assume it's a linker issue. I don't know if this is something specific to setting up C on a mac, or what -- I have been running and compiling Java / JS / Rust / Golang / Python on this machine for years, but I haven't had a need to work with C directly.

Similar error messages happen if I swap out `gcc` for `cc` or `clang`.

I would appreciate even any way to get more useful information on this error message; as it is, it's saying something doesn't exist, when it clearly does, and I'm at a loss.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419027).